# Feature Detection in OpenCV Python Bindings

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I've combed the web looking for a way to get the OpenCV 2.3.1a feature extraction/descriptor bindings to spit out any flavor of image features/descriptors(STAR/SURF/ORB/SIFT/FAST). I am well aware that OpenCV has a method called "goodFeaturesToTrack. This doesn't help me as there are no feature descriptors (which is what I really need). I have followed the documentation as listed here:

http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html

Nothing seems to work. I've tried all of the flavors of descriptors/features. I've tried using single and multiple channel images (i.e. color and black and white) and multiple image formats (8bit and 32f). I have worked with the current distribution and building the bindings from the source repo. Most of the methods result in a "unknown is not a numpy array" error. Here is an example:

```
SimpleCV:1>import cv2
SimpleCV:2>img = Image("aerospace.jpg")
SimpleCV:3>bwimg = img._getGrayscaleBitmap()
SimpleCV:4>bwimg
SimpleCV:4><iplimage(nChannels=1 width=600 height=400 widthStep=600 )>
SimpleCV:5>surfer = cv2.SURF(0.5,4,2,False,False)
SimpleCV:6>points = surfer.detect(bwimg,None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/SimpleCV-1.2-py2.6.egg/SimpleCV/Shell/Shell.pyc in <module>()
-

TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
SimpleCV:7>
```

It is worth noting that I am using SimpleCV to load the image, but the method _getGrayscaleBitmap() returns the gray 8bit IPL image used by OpenCV. I am sure this works as I use it with hundred of other OpenCV methods without incidence.

So can anyone point me to a *WORKING* example of this code on the web. I have combed through dozens of examples and found nothing that works.

Comment: For what it is worth I submitted this ticket to Willow Garage, but I would love to find a solution ASAP. 
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1582

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kat, this works for me:

```
s = cv2.SURF()
mask = uint8(ones(gray.shape))
keypoints = s.detect(gray,mask)
```

I can plot the key points and all. To get the descriptors you can try this

```
k,d = s.detect(gray,mask,False)
d = d.reshape((-1,128))
print d.shape, len(k)
```

d should have the same length at the list of key points.

I have this example in the OpenCV chapter here:
http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklth/personal/solem/book.html

Comment: Still getting the error. Can you do me a favor and tell me the type of the gray image? it looks like a numpy array. Do the cvMat and IPL Image types not work?

Comment: Okay from SimpleCV this looks like it will work:

gray = uint8(np.array(cv.GetMat(img._getGrayscaleBitmap())).transpose())

It will take me a day or so to do a proof of concept.

Comment: Yeah, it is a uint8 numpy array. The cv2 python bindings need some work, most of the features don't seem to be implemented yet.

Comment: I also came across this problem, although it could be the bindings may have been busted:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/85320


I was about to reference your python book using VLFeat (although the python wrappers are outdated). :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a PIL image. Try converting to a numpy image:
npImage = np.array(img)